# case insensitive pandas.Series.replace

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

I want to replace some values in categorical data columns with `np.nan`. What is the best method for replacing values in a case-insensitive manner while maintaining the same categories (in the same order)?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# set up a DF with ordered categories
values = ['one','two','three','na','Na','NA']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'categ' : values
})
df['categ'] = df['categ'].astype('category')
df['categ'].cat.categories = values


# replace values
df['categ'].replace(
    to_replace='na',
    value=np.nan
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe replace before converting to category

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# set up a DF with ordered categories
values = ['one','two','three','na','Na','NA']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'categ' : values
})


df['categ'] = df['categ'].str.lower().replace('na',np.nan)
```

Output

```
  categ
0    one
1    two
2  three
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
```

Comment: In my case, this works, but what if you're given a previously created dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You can also throw in a case insensitive regex flag, like so:

```
df['categ'].replace(
    to_replace=r'(?i:na)',
    regex=True,
    value=np.nan
)
```

Comment: Does this still work if `to_replace` is a list? Would it need to be a list of raw strings, e.g. (`[r'(?i:na)', r'(?i:none)']`?